# Swift OptionSetType protocol availability

Tags: swift2, protocols, availability, optionsettype

I'm writing an app in SWIFT 2.0 using Xcode 7, but my deployment target is iOS7.
While writing and `OptionSetType` struct, I've seen in the Quick Help that the availability of this protocol is iOS9.
In the "header" and official documentation nothing is mentioned, but I'm really wondering if this protocol is also available in lower iOSes versions since SWIFT 2.0 should be fine until iOS7.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all swift standard library ships with your app to AppStore, all this protocol will be available on iOS 7 and above.